# Scaling VXLAN tunnels in openvswitch

Tags: tunnel, gre, openflow, vxlan, ovs

As we're creating a cluster of tens of KVM host nodes we've chosen openvswitch as our virtual network infrastructure.

So we need to make isolated virtual networks between VMs on demand. I've seen some designs which uses VXLAN or GRE tunnels based on a mesh. But that could lead to thousands of tunnels between host nodes.

Basically we need something like Amazon VPC in our infrastructure. Can VXLAN tunnels provide us with such a service? If yes how about the scalability issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could solve this by running VXLAN on the hypervisor using software like FRR. That would imply that you run a full mesh BGP setup between your hypervisors, or use route reflectors. Then, you can create as many VNI's between your hypervisors which can be used as VPC's between virtual machines.

We've done this in a test setup and it seems to work, so we're planning on building our new hypervisors platforms this way using VXLAN.

Comment: That looks like a viable solution but a bit overdo for our setup. I'd really appreciate if you share any detailed open-source info on your test setup that is shareable but I think we need to go with something simpler. Any other simpler solution comes to mind?

Comment: https://vincent.bernat.ch/en/blog/2017-vxlan-bgp-evpn is a nice read on this topic.